# From where I can download Intel 945G Network Adapter driver?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I could find out audio driver and Intel graphics accelerator for **Windows XP**, **Intel 945G** chipset. However ***I am unable to find source for a Network Adapter driver***. Please post a download link for the same.

thanks regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the chipset driver:
[Chipset: Intel® Chipset Device Software for 945, 946, 955, 975 Chipset-Based Intel® Desktop Boards](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18033&lang=eng)

You can also simply let Intel scan and detect **all** drivers:
[Intel® Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This link should help you:

http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/cs-009249.htm

In short, check your motherboard manufacturer's website for drivers.